# MySQL select statement using array values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

I have a field in my database called populations_served.  It can contain up to four values - Adult, Adolescents, Children or Geriatric.  For example:

ROW1: Adults

ROW2: Geriatric

ROW3: Adults, Children

My search form has checkboxes for these options:

```
<input name="populations[]" type="checkbox" id="populations[]" value="Adults" />
<input name="populations[]" type="checkbox" id="populations[]" value="Adolescents" />
<input name="populations[]" type="checkbox" id="populations[]" value="Children" />
<input name="populations[]" type="checkbox" id="populations[]" value="Geriatric" />
```

I want my select statement to find any row that contains what I have checked.  If I check Adult, then ROW1 and ROW3 will be the result.  Same with Children.  If I only click Geriatric then ROW2 will be the result.  Here is what I've come up with but it doesn't appear to be working:

```
$populations = implode("', '",$_POST["populations"]);
$SQL2 = "SELECT * FROM membership WHERE populations_served IN ('$populations');";
```

This results in:

```
SELECT * FROM membership WHERE populations_served IN ('Adults', 'Children');
```

But only ROW1 is returned, not ROW1 & ROW3.  If I select all of the checkboxes then rows that only have Geriatric are returned.  I can't make sense of the results!

Here is how the database looks:

```
+---------+--------+----------------------+
| f_name  | l_name | populations_served   |
+---------+--------+----------------------+
| Anamika | Pandit | Adults               |
| Mary    | Anchor | Geriatric            |
| Roger   | Lewis  | Adults, Children     |
| Danny   | Gibson | Geriatric            |
+---------+--------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Show us how you store this data in your database's table.

Comment: **SQL injection alert** … you're inserting unfiltered user input into your database.

Comment: Database layout is in original post

Comment: $_POST["populations"] is an array from 4 checkboxes.  You can't enter any code in this field.  Can a SQL injection still be used?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regexp:

```
select *
  from (
        select 'Adults' as name union all
        select 'Geriatric' union all
        select 'Adults, Children'
       ) t
 where name regexp 'Adults|Children'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/45466)

Answer (score 0):

ROW 3 is not returned because "Adults, Children" is not one of "Adult" or "Children".
`populations_served` attribute is a string and not a SET as you're defining on `IN` clause.

Maybe it worth to have a look at [MySQL SET type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) and [FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)